# Would making a Youtube tutorial violate Apple's NDA?

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2

I didn't attend WWDC and I'm just an iOS developer and I'd like to show off a few new features of XCode 4.2 in a YouTube video. Am I allowed?

Comment: This is a legal question, not a programming question. It's off-topic here. Voting to close.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I use stackoverflow so much, I wasn't thinking about the type of question. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, **Nooooooooooooooooooooooo**!

I am not a lawyer, but it is a safe bet no is the answer. All iOS developers sign an agreement saying that they can not talk about the new stuff in the beta. I have seen some youtube videos demoing the xcode 4.2, but that is probably a violation.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok now that iOS 5 is now officially available.

But during Beta/Preview phases you should read the NDA and adhere to it. It says something along the lines that you can't make any information publicly available that you've learnt by accessing the beta builds and beta documentation. So there is only one correct answer: no, no, no.